# MySQL loss of data?

Tags: mysql, database, data-loss

I'm experiencing a problem of losing random data in my MySQL database. Data changes position so that data that once had an id of for example 28 gets data from id 32, seems completely random and i am unable to trace the cause of the problem. And sometimes the data is even completely lost, even though no DELETE command has been executed affecting the row. I have turned on logs for everything i can in MYSQL and still i cannot find any cause of the problem.

Running MySQL version 5.6.36-82.2 (10.1.30-MariaDB) from the XAMPP bundle for Windows Server.

Comment: Cool story bro. MySQL doesn't change the "position" of data (whatever that means), nor does it change the values of columns unless a DML statement is executed. If a DML statement is executed in the context of a transaction, changes made are preserved only if the transaction is committed ... either explicit COMMIT statement, or implicit commit by a DDL statement. I suspect that this isn't a problem with MySQL, it's a problem with the application interaction with the database, or problem with the application.

Comment: Any foreign keys on this table?

Comment: Alternatively, maybe this was a hardware problem? Future readers may consider checking the memory with Memtest86 and CPU with tools like OCCT